# Why shippingpostalcode is showing (variable does not exist)

Tags: trigger, custom-field, error, conditional

Here is my apex trigger but it is unable to recognise 2 fields i.e. `billingpostalcode` and `shippingpostalcode`.

```
    trigger AccountAddressTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {
        for(Account acc: Trigger.new)
       {
        if(acc.Match_Billing_Address__c && acc.BillingPostalCode!=NULL)
        {
        acc.ShippingPostalCode=acc.BillingPostalCode;
        }
       }

 //error: variable ShippingPostalCode and billingpostalcode does not exist    
}
```

Comment: I believe you are trying to solve the [trail-head](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro#challenge) challenge. I saved the same code and it works fine. Can you share a screenshot of the whole screen. Is the API Version greater than 30.0

Comment: yes API version is 36.0

Comment: @SHR I believe there is nothing wrong with your code. Try to delete this trigger,Logout to salesforce, relogin then create it again or run this trigger from your other salesforce instance. There are some scenario where other users have some problem in trailhead even there is nothing wrong in their code.

Comment: Have you checked the field level security on the two fields in question?

Answer (score -1):

I tried this code and it is working on my org. Below code is based on trail-head challenge

```
trigger AccountAddressTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {

    for(Account a : Trigger.new){
        If (a.Match_Billing_Address__c == true && a.BillingPostalCode!=Null) {
            a.ShippingPostalCode = a.BillingPostalCode;
        }   
    } 

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and there's a bug in your code. a.Match_Billing_Address__c = true should have two ==

Comment: @Davin - OPis trying to complete a trail head challenge. I have already completed this one. So I thought this code is much helpful for him. You can see this challenge here https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro#challenge . Also I updated answer with two ==.